# How to return if email is sent successfully or error in Codeigniter AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**I want return a value back to ajax from controller if and when the email is sent. Below are some code.**

In the Below code i want to set the flash data in session and it should set the either of the condition and call it back in AJAX

**COntroller**

```
public function send_reply(){
      $data = array(
      'from_email' => "jeevanseq@gmail.com", 
       'recipient' =>  $this->input->post('recipient'),
       'from_name' => "jeeva",
       'subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),
       'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
       );

       echo json_encode($data);
       $this->load->library('email'); 

         $this->email->from($data['from_email'], $data['from_name']); 
         $this->email->to($data['recipient']);
         $this->email->subject($data['subject']); 
         $this->email->message($data['message']); 

         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()) {
          $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","<span> * Email sent successfully. </span> "); 

         //$this->load->view('adminhp'); 
         } else {

          $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","<span> * Error in sending Email.</span> "); 
        // $this->load->view('adminhp'); 


       }
       }
```

**Ajax Code**

```
// Ajax post for email sending
$(document).ready(  function() {
$(".mailsub").click(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
var recipient = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('input.recipient').val();
var subject = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('input.subject').val();
var message = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('textarea.message').val();

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/user_authentication/send_reply",
dataType: 'json',
data: {recipient: recipient, subject: subject, message:message},
success: function(result) {
if (result)
{
// Show Entered Value
jQuery("div#result").show();
jQuery("div#rslt").html("Sent Successfully");
console.log("Success");

}
}
});
});
});
```

I want to set it the flash data in below code

```
echo "<br/>";
echo "<div id='result' style='display: none'>";
echo "<div id='rslt' style='display:inline'></div>";
// echo $this->session->flashdata('email_sent'); 
echo "</div>";
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Setting a `flash_data` wont help to achieve your goal. You have to echo from the controller for access it through `ajax`. After echoing from php, you can test the value using `alert(result)` inside the `ajax success`

Comment: Success is fine. What if the email is not sent. can you please give me a snippet in this regard. that would be very helpful

Comment: To use flashdata, you should use `redirect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST in controller you have to echo the message**

```
 $msg = '';
 if($this->email->send()) {
     $msg = 'Email sent successfully'; 
 } else {   
     $msg ='Error in sending'; 
   }
 echo $msg;die;
```

**SECOND in ajax just add the respone to the corresponding div:**

```
  success: function(result) {
           if (result)
           {
                console.log(result);
                jQuery("div#result").show();
                jQuery("div#rslt").html(result);

           }
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens with this code. From code it used to display "Sent successfully " Message for everything even if the mail was not sent. Any correction to be made in your code sir!

Comment: use this code and if it is always show message " email sent successfully" then problem in the emai->send() which always return true even if email is not sent

Comment: sorry i guess u mistook my comment ..from your code nothing is happening ..its empty. i meant from my code what i posted in the question above always used to show "sent successfully". your code is not doing anything though my message is sent to the recipient. Any Changes to make in your code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to see the edit u had done above in the answer. I'll try that.

Comment: are You sure your console is not showing any data? put something else like console.log('test_data'); and see  console output

Comment: by the way there is no need to define dataType :'json' in ajax

Comment: Thanks Mate it worked!! i had to remove the echo json_encode from Controller and dataType:Json from Ajax. Thanks a Lot!!